# Diffrence between binding in function and out of function

Tags: c, variables, binding

First I code like this. but this get error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int array[2][4]={1,2,3,4,5,8,9,0};
int (*p)[4]=NULL;
p=array;
int main(){

  int j;
  for(j=0;j<4;j++){
    printf("%d",p[1][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

After that I modify my code like this. 
I just put p=array; into int main()

```
#include <stdio.h>
int array[2][4]={1,2,3,4,5,8,9,0};
int (*p)[4]=NULL;

int main(){
  p=array;
  int j;
  for(j=0;j<4;j++){
    printf("%d",p[1][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why do they have different operation?

Comment: Please add the *error* into your question too! (What error)

Comment: Perhaps even ask something about the error, such as the meaning of the words that confuse you!

Comment: The first example is invalid C and the second compiles? What is the question?

Comment: Sorry. I will add the error into my question from now on.

Answer (score 2):

`p=array;` statement is an assignment statement and must be performed inside a function.

Comment: I'm not native English people, so my English writing is terrible.  Although I ask unclear question, your answer is very clear and simple. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare and define *global* variable

```
int (*p)[4]=NULL;
```

Then you execute code (which is prohibited outside any function)

```
p=array;
```

Instead, you can do this

```
int (*p)[4]=array;
```

or explicitly declare and define like this

```
int (*p)[4];
int (*p)[4] = array;
```

Comment: Aha~~ I'm surprise that you can understand what is my question. My question is vague. Thank you for your clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
p=array
```

is an assignment statement which cannot be performed outside an function.
As declaration should can be done anywhere inside a function (local declaration) or outside a function (global declaration) but assignment should be done inside a function only.

Though declaration and assignment at the same time can be done globally (like in your code):

```
int array[2][4]={1,2,3,4,5,8,9,0};
int (*p)[4]=NULL;
```